# Как найти большее и меньшее число и через for сравнить?

Tags: php

Есть 2 числа и я не понимаю, как хранить числа? Задавать им новые переменные и там их между собой сравнивать? Мне кажется я сделаю кашу, можно немного просветить, как правильно сделать.
Пример:
$num1 = 2;
$num2 = 8;
И в любом случае я должен найти из этих чисел "большое" и уже через for сделать от него "8 6 4 2".
Вот проблема в сравнивании чисел...

Comment: заведите `$min/$max` да туда впишите результат сравнения

Comment: Вот в этом и проблема, что num1 и num2 может быть большее или меньшее. т.е мне несколько раз продублировать min&max? или их сравнить потом между собой?или через rand подставить?

Comment: `$min = $num1 > $num2 ? $num2 : $num1;` для `$max` по аналогии. либо `if` для обоих. сразу

Comment: Все, спасибо, сам себе задачу услажняю. Можно ведь и IF использовать, а то как скажут...Только через for решать и сижу, как животное, не знаю что делать...Спасибо)

Comment: через `for` вам сказано сделать ряд 8 6 4 2